# Validate upload size before starting upload with Filefield?

Tags: 6, files, forms

I'm doing some pretty massive uploads, up to 1gig. Right now if I upload a 1.1 gig file it uploads to the limit then fails.

Is there any way to make it fail before even beginning the upload?

Answer (score 2):

The only easy way to check a file upload's size on the client-side that I know of is with Flash.

You should see if the [Uploadify module](http://drupal.org/project/uploadify)  works for you. I haven't used the module, but I have used Uploadify a lot, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them, but check out the [Webform module](http://drupal.org/project/webform) and the companion [Webform Validation module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation), together with the [patch on comment #4 in this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1197284#comment-4644134).

You may be able to avoid writing your own client-side validation with JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: How would I apply these to a node form's filefield validation?

Comment: The issue is you need to do the validation in the client, so that requires javascript running in the browser.  All of drupal's standard validation is done on the server side of things, as you've seen, after the form has been submitted.  So, you are asking for a book sized answer here, hence my suggestion that you look at the two projects and patch, as they appear to create all the form validations "out of the box" you are looking for.